# Unable to run Apache Tomcat server on my localhost?

Tags: java, eclipse, apache, tomcat, tomcat8

I am trying to run Apache Tomcat server on my local machine and unable to start the server from last 1 day. I tried different post to troubleshoot this problem on Stack Overflow but none worked in my case.

I tried below steps:

1. Install Java JDK and Java JRE (both version 1.8)
2. Install Tomcat with same version (Tomcat 8)
3. Set correct `CATALINA_HOME` path pointing to Apache Tomcat directory
4. Run `startup.bat` file inside `Apache Tomcat/bin` folder

While running `startup.bat` file, I am getting below error in log file:

```
04-Dec-2016 22:30:59.501 SEVERE [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.load Catalina.start
org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to initialize component [StandardServer[8005]]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.load(Catalina.java:580)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.load(Catalina.java:603)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.load(Bootstrap.java:310)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:484)
Caused by: org.w3c.dom.ls.LSException: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.apache.xml.serialize.DOMSerializerImpl.writeToString(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.JreMemoryLeakPreventionListener.lifecycleEvent(JreMemoryLeakPreventionListener.java:426)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:95)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:90)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.setStateInternal(LifecycleBase.java:388)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:101)
... 8 more
```

Two error encuntered are:

```
org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.load Catalina.start
org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to initialize component
```

and

```
org.w3c.dom.ls.LSException: java.lang.NullPointerException
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you have library issue .

Try to  use the latest version of Xerces library  ,

put `"xercesImpl.jar" and "xml-apis.jar"` in `TOMCAT_HOME/endorsed` folder

Comment: I have placed the these two jar files in TOMCAT_HOME/lib folder but still getting same error. Please help
what does **TOMCAT_HOME/endorsed** directory means?